# Fractal homological algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, fractals

The usual definition of a chain complex requires for the indices to be integer numbers. However, taking inspiration from the theory of Hausdorff dimension, one can think of 'fractal' chain complexes (of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces), i.e. $\mathbb{R}$-graded vector spaces $$V=\bigoplus_{\phi \in \mathbb{R}} V_{\phi}$$ equipped with a differential $d: \ V_{\phi} \to V_{\phi +1}$, $d^2=0$.

One can also endow the category of such chain complexes with a monoidal structure, by setting $(V  \otimes W)_{\phi} = \bigoplus_{\alpha + \beta=\phi} V_{\alpha} \otimes W_{\beta}$ with differential given by
$$d(v \otimes w) = dv \otimes w + e^{\pi \sqrt{-1} \alpha} v \otimes dw$$
when $v \in V_{\alpha}$ (this is somehow a 'fractal' Leibniz rule). We can thus speak of fractal differential graded algebras and categories (i.e. categories enriched over the abovementioned monoidal category) and much more.

The question is: are such constructions present somewhere in literature? Has anyone heard of any attempt to introduce fractal dimensions into homological algebra?

Comment: Not sure how fractal this really is, but have you looked into [Hopfological algebra](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1814)?

Comment: There are similar constructions in differential calculus with the idea of a "fractional derivative". I would think that fractional is more appropriate than fractal in this context too.

Comment: As long as you have a single differential with fixed degree $+1$, these complexes are just direct sums of independent ordered $\mathbb Z$-indexed chain complexes, namely one for each coset of $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. A more interesting structure would be something that connects all degree with each other. Maybe a family of differentials $(d^\alpha)_{\alpha\geq 0}$ with $d^0=id$, $d^{\alpha+\beta} = d^\alpha \circ d^\beta$ and $d^c = 0$ for some fixed cutoff $c>0$, but I do not know if such a thing is useful in any way.

Comment: Being useful really is the key here. You should figure out at least one example where such an idea can be useful. Is there a geometric/topological/space-ish thing that has 1/2-dimensional "holes" ? Is there anything that feels like it is "between third and fourth cohomology" ? Stuff like that. Find something useful and the right definition may come naturally out of it (that's of course not guaranteed, but it is very much possible)

Comment: Just a thought, you might literally be able to use fractional derivatives in some sort of fractional de Rham complex. I would guess it would have problems but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm aware of that work. However, it is quite different since the differential is required to satisfy $d^n=0$ for some fixed $n$.

Comment: @JohannesHahn A fractional complex in this sense is, as you say, just a $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$-collection of complexes. However, the monoidal structure is nontrivial: this means that enriched categories (i.e. fractional dg-categories) have interesting structure. I can't think of an example, unfortunately.  The fractional De Rham complex idea by Ali could work.

Comment: @gm01 There would have to be some sort of rationally indexed chain complex before you can get them indexed by reals.  For this "de Rham" complex it would be impossible because a $(1/2)$-form wouldn't make much sense due to the properties of the underlying algebraic structures. For something like that to work, the structures would have to be vastly different to vector spaces which lends itself to being hideously complicated. Chain complexes naturally work over $\Bbb Z$-graded things so the objects themselves would have to be "real ly" graded.